# How to accept TCP stream from client (video stream)?

Tags: c#, tcp

I trying to get video stream from client on TCP connection.

I define a socket on the code below - but i don't know how to continue it. 
I need to wait until client will connect - and listen until the client will close the tcp connection -

I don't know how to accept the stream from the client - and how to keep the byte stream and save all the video on incoming stream data

```
public void Connect(int port)
{
    Socket server = 
        new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

    server.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, port));

    server.Listen(100);

    while (true)
    {
        Socket clientSocket = server.Accept();
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't work with the Socket class, use a higher level wrapper like [TcpListener](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I think the simplest way would be:

```
TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 12345);
listener.Start();

while (true)
{
    var client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        //Create a new file for every connection
        using (var file = File.Create(Guid.NewGuid() + ".dat"))
        {
            client.GetStream().CopyTo(file);
        }
    }, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
}
```

*PS: Tested with ffmpeg streaming video to port 12345*

```
ffmpeg.exe -i aa.mp4 -f mpegts tcp://localhost:12345
```